# Regression Specification Error Test (RESET)

Tags: regression

I'm trying to understand the RESET Test for Regression Models. We assume that the dependend variable y is a function of the indenpendend variable x. We can write $y=f(x)\approx \beta_0+\beta_1x+\beta_2x^2+\beta_3x^3+\ldots$ because of the Taylor Expansion.

Now my question: Why don't we regress y on $x, x^2, x^3$ and look at the significance of $\beta_2, \beta_3$? Because the Reset Test instead regress y on $x, \hat{y}^2,\hat{y}^3$ ...

I hope someone could explain or give me a hint.